# Context initialization failed using Spring

Tags: java, spring

I got an error when running my web app 'parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]' which means that it didn't find the path I specified in springbeans.xml. So tried another approach as follows:

web.xml (The important part)

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>
      spring
   </servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>
   spring
</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>     
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
   </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- 
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>C:\Users\alamo\eclipse- 
workspace\coreproject\src\main\resources\SpringBeans.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
 -->
<listener>
  <listener-class>
  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
```

First, I tried with just the context-param and the load listener, and then I add the servlet part and I moved the Springbeans.xml to the folder WEB-INF and renamed it to spring-servlet.xml. The version of spring is 3.2.16.

spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.

       PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 

  <property name="location">
 <value>C:\Users\alamo\eclipse- 
      workspace\coreproject\src\main\resources\application.properties
     </value>
 </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"

    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" 
     value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="myAction" class="coreproject.action.MyAction">
<property name="userProvider" ref="userProvider" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="userProvider" class="coreproject.provider.UserProviderImpl">
<property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO" />
</bean>

<bean id="userDAO" class="coreproject.dao.UserDAOImpl">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

    </beans>
```

I'm still getting the same error. What can I do?

Comment: Can you specify why contextConfigLocation is commented out in the web.xml?

Comment: Are you just learning Spring or working on an old existing application? Nearly everything here is obsolete and can be done much more easily with newer tools.

Comment: Remove the `ContextLoaderListener` that by default will load a file called `applicationContext.xml` you don't have it hence it fails. Also the `location` for the `PropertyPlaceholdeConfigurer`  should read `classpath:application.properties` not what you have now.

Comment: I know it's an obsolete way to do it, but in my work they seem to do things this way. I removed the ContextLoaderListener and I put the classpath, but now it gives me error 404.